# Joint density from conditionals?

Tags: probability

For three random variables $X,Y,Z$, I'm given the conditional densities

$$
  f_{X\mid Y,Z} \qquad\qquad f_{Y\mid X,Z} \qquad\qquad f_{Z\mid X,Y} 
$$

Are there any known sufficient consistency conditions that guarantee that a joint density of $X,Y,X$ exists? If the conditions are fulfilled, how do I compute the joint density?

Comment: Nice question. In which context did you stumble on it? What did you try to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The literature on Gibbs Sampling is probably useful here. One result discussed in MCMC books (like Robert and Casella *Monte Carlo  Statistical Methods*) is the Hammersley-Clifford Theorem, which states that, if the joint density exists, then you can compute it from the full conditionals in a certain way. Of course, this result does not give you a complete answer, since you don't know if the joint density exists, but this is the place where I would start searching. Good luck.